# Entity framework Core eager load - including multiple levels

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity framework Core and I have the following model classes.

```
class A {
    [Key]
    public string AId { get; set; }
    ....
    public List<A_B> A_Bs { get; set; }
}
class A_B {
    [Key]
    public String AId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Int16 BId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public B B { get; set; }
}
class B {
    [Key]
    public Int16 Id { get; set; }
    .... // Other properties of B
}
```

And according to the this page https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html, the following code should work.

```
context.A
    .Include(e => e.A_Bs)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.B) // x has the type of List<A_B> instead of A_B
```

However, the type of `x` is `List<A_B>` and it doesn't have the property of `B`?

Comment: The type of `x` is `A_B`.

Comment: On my PC it's `List<A_B>`, same as `e.A_Bs`?

Comment: So your code doesn't run?

Comment: It must be a bug of Visual studio. The intelligence shows the type of `List<A_B>` and it doesn't prompt `.B` when typing. However, I just typed it and it works and even the type hint is `A_B` now.

Comment: Or `Include()` is polymorphic and VS just messed up.

Comment: Use ICollection<A_B>  instead of List<A_B> as the property type.

Comment: @E-Bat What's the benefit to use ICollection over List for EF? I followed some official examples which use List?

Comment: If you are only worried that intellisense doesn't show anything for ThenInclude(...) it's a known issue. Still works fine.

Comment: @alanh I'm glad it works fine. But it was really confused.

Comment: By using ICollection you are covered from EF internal implementation changes for collections.

Comment: @E-Bat But List also implemented ICollection, so List should also be covered?

Comment: List is just one of many implementation of ICollection, declaring your property as List will wire your objects to it. Having EF change the internal implementation detail your code will need to be refactored. By using ICollection and leverage the instantiation to EF you will be safe.